# Get array of all UITextFields

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

How can I get an array of all UITextFields in a view controller?

EDIT: I do not want to hardcode the textfields into an array. I actually want to get the list inside the delegate of all the fields from the caller of that delegate.

Comment: Add them to an array when you create them???

Comment: Please note that the delegate does not contain references to the textfields, it's the other way around and there's no way to find the fields from the delegate alone.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Recursive implementation to search all subviews' subviews:  (this way you catch textfields embedded in uiscrollview, etc)

```
-(NSArray*)findAllTextFieldsInView:(UIView*)view{
    NSMutableArray* textfieldarray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    for(id x in [view subviews]){
        if([x isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            [textfieldarray addObject:x];

        if([x respondsToSelector:@selector(subviews)]){
            // if it has subviews, loop through those, too
            [textfieldarray addObjectsFromArray:[self findAllTextFieldsInView:x]];
        }
    }
    return textfieldarray;
}

-(void)myMethod{
   NSArray* allTextFields = [self findAllTextFieldsInView:[self view]];
   // ...
 }
```

Comment: Isn't this `if([x respondsToSelector:@selector(subviews)]){` redundant as `-subviews` returns `@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *subviews`. Therefore any item in that array will be of type `UIView` or a subclass or `UIView`, which responds to `@selector(subviews)`

Comment: I'm just very shaky about throwing messages to objects for which I don't even know the class - what if some bonehead subclassed `UIView` in such a way that `subviews` contains non-`UIView`-inherited objects, and thus objects that don't respond to `@selector(subviews)`?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to override the method and add non `UIView`'s - if a user does they would most likely be clever enough to know why they are doing it and any risks that it may involve. At least that's what one would hope ;)

Comment: @jostster This solution doesn't require you hardcode an array.  Any UITextField which is added to a view either through `addSubview` or Interface Builder automatically has the `subviews` array.

Comment: @Tim I am using your code with a few alterations. Basically I put findAllTextFieldsInView in my TextFieldDelegate class and in my views calling that on load. I will need to set a variable in TextFieldDelegate from the view to the controller so when the delegate calls findAllTextFieldsInView it will parse the controller. How can I do this? My controllers can be either a UIViewController or UITableViewController.

Comment: Simply pass in `[viewController view]` as the argument to the method.

Comment: @Tim I am doing that however it doesn't seem to be able to find any UITextFields.

Comment: This won't work with a UITableViewController, unless you loop through all possible cells using a combination of `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to get all the cells, and then pass each one into my method.

Comment: @Tim How would this include getting textfields inside of custom UITableViewCells?

Comment: Note: `f([x isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])` should read `f([x isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])` because point is that it is counting textFields not textViews ( credit: @narco )

Comment: In ios 10 (possibly 9 too), when a text field is inside a Stack view I am seeing this. ``Could not cast value of type '_UILayoutGuide' (0x104ff9e38) to 'UITextField' (0x104ffec08).``

Answer (score 3):

If you know you need an `NSArray` containing all the `UITextField`'s then why not add them to an array?

```
NSMutableArray *textFields = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];

[textFields addObject:textField]; // <- repeat for each UITextField
```

If you are using a nib then use an `IBOutletCollection`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UITextField) NSArray *textFields;
```

Then connect all the `UITextField`'s to that array

Comment: hard coding them into an array is pointless... Defeats the purpose of me wanting to get an array of all textfields as I can just create it manually...

Comment: There is no hardcoding if you add the `UITextField`'s to an `NSMutableArray` as and when you create them

Comment: I will be creating textfields based off data coming from an API so I won't know what text fields are there. I could just add them programmatically when I create them but I would prefer to just grab a list of fields that already exist instead of depending on a developer to add each field to an array.

Comment: Why add them and then in a second pass go and find them? That sounds very inefficient. If you want a reference to the `UITextField` add it to an array when you create it (and already have the reference).

Answer (score 1):

-Use following code to get array that contains text values of all UITextField presented on View:

```
   NSMutableArray *addressArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   for(id aSubView in [self.view subviews])
   {
           if([aSubView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
           {
                  UITextField *textField=(UITextField*)aSubView;
                  [addressArray addObject:textField.text];
           }
   }
   NSLog(@"%@", addressArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
extension UIView 
{
   class func getAllSubviewsOfType<T: UIView>(view: UIView) -> [T] 
   {
       return view.subviews.flatMap { subView -> [T] in
       var result = UIView.getAllSubviewsOfType(view: subView) as [T]
       if let view = subView as? T {
           result.append(view)
       }
       return result
     }
   }

   func getAllSubviewsWithType<T: UIView>() -> [T] {
       return UIView.getAllSubviewsOfType(view: self.view) as [T]
   }
}
```

How to use with Text Fields:

```
let textFields = self.view.getAllSubviewsWithType() as [UITextField]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through the controller's view's subviews.

Here's a ***rough*** example:

```
NSMutableArray *arrOfTextFields = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id subView in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
       [arrOfTextFields addObject:subView]; 
}
```

Comment: This will not catch the UITextFields embedded in other views.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT** Recursion without global variable (Just for Tim)

```
-(NSArray*)performUIElementSearchForClass:(Class)targetClass onView:(UIView*)root{

    NSMutableArray *searchCollection = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    for(UIView *subview in root.subviews){

        if ([subView isKindOfClass:targetClass])  
            [searchCollection addObject:subview];

        if(subview.subviews.count > 0)
            [searchCollection addObjectsFromArray:[self performUIElementSearchForClass:targetClass onView:subview]];

    }

    return searchCollection;
}
```

Comment: I find myself often typing like this on SO:  `NSMutableArray ]alloc] init ]autorelease` XCode spoils me so :P

Comment: This will not catch the UITextFields embedded in other views.

Comment: Recursion, but using a global variable?  UNHOLY!