# Add the contents of a UITextField to an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, nsmutablearray

How can I put an element coming from a `UITextField` into an `NSMutableArray`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Array should be of mutable type NSMutableArray *yourArray=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [yourArray addObject:[textfield text]];
    NSLog([yourArray description],nil);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this works now, do you know how to print the contents of my array so that I could check if elements are added successfully?

Comment: @Hans, array should be of mutable type, e.g. `NSMutableArray *yourArray=[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the text from textfield:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

     NSString *lTemp = textField.text;

     //Add to your array
     [lMutableArray addObject: lTemp];
  }
```

Comment: This adds an extra step however and is not suggested. In every interview I have had address why @kuldeep's method is the better of the two.

Answer (score 0):

check code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857792/get-array-of-all-uitextfields/14996550#14996550), Here I am adding text values of all textfields in NSMutableArray presented on View.